# Copied this exact code from my book and does not work

Tags: java

I copied this exact code from my textbook, and when I try to run it it does nothing but load, the file is in the same location of the java file, and the name is correct. Im using Dr. Java. So im just wondering why it wont run and just keeps loading. The book I am using is Java Illuminated 3rd edition. Also, the newscores.txt file just has 10 numbers, seperated by spaces.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public class TestScoresAndSummaryStatistics {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        int number;

        File inputFile = new File("newscores.txt");
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(inputFile);

        while (scan.hasNext()); {
            number = scan.nextInt();
            System.out.println(number);

        }
        System.out.println("End of file.");
    }
}
```

Comment: What IDE are you using?

Comment: How do you know for certain it's just running? can you add a print statement within the very first line of the main method and see if that gets printed?

Comment: Im using Dr. Java, and I just tried adding a print statement in the beginning of the code and it printed it, but then just kept loading as usual.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have a  semicolon end of while statement .you should remove it.because of this semicolon your while loop run repeatedly and your code inside while loop become separate block from the loop.

```
while (scan.hasNext()); {
    number = scan.nextInt();
    System.out.println(number);

}
```

change to

```
while (scan.hasNext()) {
    number = scan.nextInt();
    System.out.println(number);

}
```

Comment: Wow, I have been working on this for over an hour now, thanks, that fixed it.